# display output in html page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

```
function shuffleArray(a, n) {
  let i=0,q=1,k=n
  while(i<n){
    for (let j = k; j > i + q; j--) {
      let temp = a[j - 1];
      a[j - 1] = a[j];
      a[j] = temp;
    }
    i++; 
    k++; 
    q++;
}
 return a;
}

a = [2,1,5,3,11,7]
shuffleArray(a, a.length / 2);
document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = a;

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Shuffle</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1 class="a">Shuffle Array Program</h1>
        <h2>Input array : [2, 1, 5, 3, 11, 7] </h2>
        <button onClick=shuffleArray([2, 1, 5, 3, 11, 7],a.length/2)>shuffleArray</button>
        <h2>Output Array : </h2>  <span id="op">Answer : </span>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

I was trying out .innerHtml method , when i click on the button the answer gets displayed in the broser, the JS code is working fine , but little confused on how to use it with HTML file, can anyone help me with this resolution ?

Comment: If it's working fine.. what is your question?

Comment: js code is working fine, but output to be displayed in browser is not working out.. Like the output for the function needed to be displayed in browser where the id is "op"

Comment: `a` appears to be an array, while `innerHTML` is a string. Is there an error in your console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shuffled array has to be converted to a string (I did it with a `.join(', ')`:

```js
let a = [2, 1, 5, 3, 11, 7];

const updateOutput = (arr) => {
  const op = document.getElementById('op')
  op.innerHTML = arr.join(', ')
}

const btnShuffle = document.getElementById('shuffle')
btnShuffle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const shuffled = shuffleArray(a, a.length / 2)
  updateOutput(shuffled)
})

function shuffleArray(a, n) {
  let i = 0,
    q = 1,
    k = n;
  while (i < n) {
    for (let j = k; j > i + q; j--) {
      let temp = a[j - 1];
      a[j - 1] = a[j];
      a[j] = temp;
    }
    i++;
    k++;
    q++;
  }
  return a;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shuffle Array Program</h1>
<h2>Input array: [2, 1, 5, 3, 11, 7] </h2>
<button id="shuffle">shuffleArray</button>
<h2>Output Array: </h2>Answer: <span id="op"></span>
```

Comment: thanks @muka.gergely "The shuffled array has to be converted to a string (I did it with a .join(', '):" noted!